# Change image'size

Tags: python-3.x

I want to change a image'size to use it in tkinter. I don't know if I had to do a scale or what. But if that is the case I want to know how can i do it.

Comment: Downvote: Can you please state how you want to texpect, for example provide an expected result? Otherwise this question doesn't seem clear at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this recently. Not quite sure if this is what you mean but here's what I did:

```
    photo = PhotoImage(file=resource_path("logo.png"))
    photo = photo.zoom(5, 2)
    photo_label = Label(initialFrame, image=photo)
    photo_label.img = photo
    photo_label.pack()
```

`photo.zoom(x, y)` will scale the image x horizontally and y vertically. If you were just asking how to place an image in tkinter frame then it's the same minus the photo.zoom() line.